# Move packages from android studio to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I would like to use the `android.os` package from Android Studio and SDK in eclipse. This is so that I can run a java application on my computer to take data off of a sd card on a phone when it is plugged in via USB. I have both Android Studio and Eclipse on my computer but I don't want to develop a program on the phone it's self, thus why I want to use eclipse. This should work the same as copying files off of an external drive.

Is there a way for me to copy these packages and install them on eclipse?

Comment: you could just download IntelliJ Community Edition (which Android Studio is based on) and develop using that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use IntelliJ.

And if you are a student, use your university email address to register/apply for a complete version of software with all functionalities included. Just google for "intellij student".

IMHO it's better than eclipse for what you are planning to do.